# set case of content bound via content controls in docx

Tags: ms-word, docx, docx4j

I have a docx file that contains a custom part and a web page that collects input from the user to populate that custom part.  One of my "variables" is used multiple times in the document.  In some cases, I need it to appear in ALL CAPS.  In most cases, it should appear as the user entered it in the web form.  We're using docx4j version 3.2.1.

Previously we used "mail merge" fields which allowed for instructions like `/* UPPER */` and `/* CAPS */`.

is there a way to get that same behavior using content controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set the rPr property on a plain text content control to include:

http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/WordML/caps.html

Failing that, its not elegant, but you could always include a second element in your XML with the caps form.

Comment: yeah, I was afraid of that....I'm not creating the...the "user" is and I'd have no idea which usages of the binding should be in all caps.  I have already started to generate a UPPER and Caps version of each binding so the user can choose the correct version of the value to use.  Thanks for the awesome product and help!

Comment: Re the first alternative, you could define an uppercase style; that can then be applied to the content control via Word's Developer menu: Properties > "Use a style to format contents".  Or you could create a macro to do it.  This should work fine, since it doesn't require docx4j to do anything to capitalize the text it injects.